# Declare as object property vs pass as argument

Tags: javascript

When is it better to define a property on an object, or to pass a local variable around as argument?

Simplified example:

```
var obj = function(){

    this.method_1 = function(){ 
        this.var_1 = 1; 
        this.method_2(); 
    }; 

    this.method_2 = function(){ 
        //Access var_1 
        var_3 = this.var_1 * 2; 
    }; 
};
```

versus

```
var obj = function(){

    this.method_1 = function(){ 
        var var_1 = 1; 
        this.method_2(var_1); 
    }; 

    this.method_2 = function(var_1){ 
        //Access var_1 
        var_3 = var_1 * 2; 
    }; 
};
```

Does it matter?

Edit: I should have mentioned this before probably, but still:

The case I have is that a Google Map instance is created by a method on the mapPresenter object; this method is only executed after being triggered by a certain event. Although I don't need the map instance to be accessible from outside, I use it in a number of methods on the presenter object itself, which would make it "easier" to set a property on the presenter object.

Comment: For one difference, you can't use the second way from "the outside", as you don't have a reference to var_1. If you don't need to call method_2 from the outside, you needn't put it on `this`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. In the question I want to assume that I only need access to the variable within the object itself.

Comment: @KimGysen Then that info should be in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a property only if you need to access it from the outside, and when the value is logically part of the instance. If it is a value only needed for the call, then you should use a method argument. That you are creating the property here in a method call, not on instantiation (in the constructor) should serve as a warning smell.

```
function Obj() {
    this.var_1 = 1; 

    this.method = function() { 
        return this.var_1 * 2; 
    }; 
}
var o = new Obj;
console.log(o.var_1);
console.log(o.method());
```

versus

```
function Obj() {
    this.method = function(var_1) { 
        return var_1 * 2; 
    }; 
}
var o = new Obj;
console.log(o.method(1));
```

Comment: The case I have is that a Google Map instance is created by a method on the mapPresenter object; this method is only executed after being triggered by a certain event. Although I don't need the map instance to be accessible from outside, I use it in a number of methods on the presenter object itself, which would make it "easier" to set a property on the presenter object.

Comment: First: showing real code in your question helps :-) But yes, that sounds as if there is one GoogleMap instance belonging to your mapPresenter object, so it would be fine as a property. However, what can the mapPresenter instance do without the map, is it any useful? And what happens if the event happens not only once, and that method is executed multiple times? Maybe it would be cleaner to instantiate your whole mapPresenter only when that event happens, and initialise it with the map object.

Comment: Yes, I tried to simplify, but that was perhaps not a good idea for this case. The mapPresenter absolutely needs the map instance. Yes, I might have a second look at the architecture, there might be a few things to tweak. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my 2 cents. It's just a matter of what you want to be accessible from outside your object

Both methods accessible, property not accessible

```
var obj = function(){

var var_1 = 1;
var var_3;

this.method_1 = function(){       
    this.method_2(); 
}; 

this.method_2 = function(){         
    var_3 = var_1 * 2; 
}; 
};
```

Or even

Only one method accessible, property not accessible

```
var obj = function(){

var var_1 = 1;
var var_3;

this.method_1 = function(){       
    method_2(); 
}; 

function method_2 (){         
    var_3 = var_1 * 2; 
}; 
};
```

Or even

One method accessible, both properties accessible

```
var obj = function(){

this.var_1 = 1;
this.var_3;

this.method_1 = function(){       
    method_2(); 
}; 

function method_2 (){         
    this.var_3 = this.var_1 * 2; 
}; 
};
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer, but here's something to consider:

Does var_1 mean anything to obj once method_1 has completed?  Or is var_1 simply an aid to computation.

I would prefer to keep the data model in normal form.  If var_1 is a property of another object, then don't also store it in obj, consider creating a reference to the other object in obj directly, (obj.related.var_1).

If you are constructing many objs in memory, passing var_1 as a parameter would reduce the memory footprint.

I guess method_1 could be rewritten as
method_1 = bind(obj, 1);

Also, add method_1 and method_2 to the prototype so only one function instance is created.

Comment: Sorry that this is late, but I've edited the question details to provide more info about the case.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is persistence of the value and the state of the object.

Using `var_1` as a **property** means that value will be persisted until changed. As others have stated, that means it can be accessed outside the object, or accessed at a later time. However, because it is persisted, it will take more memory, and could lead to a memory leak (if `var_1` was sufficiently complex, such as another instance of obj).

Using `var_1` as an **argument** means it will be lost after the function completes. Thus, it cannot be accessed outside the object and will not cause a memory leak. However, it is more difficult to debug.

Generally, properties represent the state of the object, whereas arguments provide information on how to act. Ask yourself, do you need `var_1` ever again? If you do, storing it as a property is reasonable. If not, stick with it as an argument.

In non Javascript languages, the argument route is better for multi-threaded behavior, since properties can change without warning.

For what it's worth, here is a third option, which holds var_1 as a private property

```
//var_1 persisted but not publicly available
var obj = function(){
    var var_1;

    this.method_1 = function(){ 
        var_1 = 1; 
        this.method_2(); 
    }; 

    this.method_2 = function(){ 
        //Access var_1 
        var_3 = var_1 * 2; 
    }; 
};
```